# Making Indy return utf-8 strings instead of ansi strings in FPC/Lazarus?

Tags: internationalization, indy, lazarus, freepascal, indy10

Are there any compiler directives or preprocessor commands that need to be set in a particular way to make Indy return Utf-8 strings rather than truncating them into Ansi strings? The project I'm working on has all kinds of Delphi-mode flags all over it if that matters.

If I directly set the subject line to a UTF-8 string (like below) it displays correctly on the GUI, so utf-8 support is set up correctly and I'm using an appropriate font and all of that good stuff. Subject is declared as Utf8String for clarity in this code.

`MailItem.Subject := 'îņŢëŕŃïóЙǟŁ ŜũƥĵεϿד'; //Displays correctly`

However, if I pull the same subject line from the header, using Indy to decode it, I get every international character replaced with exactly one question-mark, exactly the number of should-be characters. Looks like it's converting UTF-8 to ANSI, which is not what I want.

`MailItem.Subject := IdCoderHeader.DecodeHeader('=?utf-8?B?w67FhsWiw6vFlcWDw6/Ds9CZx5/FgSDFnMWpxqXEtc61z7/Xkw==?='); //Displays '?????????? ???????'`

So what things could be going wrong and/or how can I fix it?

I am using the latest version of Indy10 from Indy's website, and Lazarus 1.0 on Windows, so I don't think this is a "my software needs updating" bug, I think it's probably some sort of configuration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no compiler flags you can set for that.

Indy uses `AnsiString` in Delphi prior to D2009, and in FreePascal prior to 3.0.  Indy uses `UnicodeString` in Delphi 2009+ and FreePascal 3.0+.  There is no option to change that.

However, in non-Unicode versions of Delphi and FreePascal, in some places of Indy, you can instruct Indy to interpret `AnsiString` input values as UTF-8, and return UTF-8 encoded `AnsiString` output.  However, `DecodeHeader()` is not one of those places.